# Im not sure what functions to use when sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Im not sure what functions to use to sort a dictionary which gets added to as the programme runs, the format of the dictionary is (name:score,name:score ..... )

```
print(" AZ : print out the scores of the selected class alphabteically \n HL : print out the scores of the selected class highest to lowest \n AV : print out the scores of the selected class with there average scores highest to lowest")
    choice = input("How would you like the data to be presented? (AZ/HL/AV)")

while True:
if choice.lower() == 'az':
  for entry in sorted(diction1.items(), key=lambda t:t[0]):
  print(diction1)
  break
elif choice.lower()=='hl':
  for entry in sorted(diction1.items(), key=lambda t:t[1]):
  print(diction1)
  break
elif choice.lower() == 'av':
  print(diction1)
  break
else:
  print("invalid entry")
  break
```

Comment: First: your python code is a mess of indentation. Nobody can read it, and second, what is the question?

Comment: What functions do I use to sort my dictionary so it reads either alphabetically or highest to lowest?

Comment: Python's dictionary is unordered; use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead

Comment: how do you use that?

Comment: While they're an awesome tool to have in your python toolkit, `OrderedDict` is probably not the right data structure for this usecase, since a) you don't want the data to be in order of insertion but rather in several other sort orders, and b) you are going to be adding data as you go along.  Unless you rarely make additions and the sorting-upon-request is proving to be a bottleneck, it's better to go with @matthias' solution below.

Comment: I have but the one he told me about how to sort the values doesnot work, as I want to sort them from highest to lowest

Comment: by the way, the docs that @dazedconfused links to in his comment has some great examples so you should be able to figure it out pretty easily from there.

Comment: Woops wrong index.  For highest to lowest: `for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):`

Answer (score 2):

A `dictionary` is unordered.

You can sort the data for output.

```
>>> data = {'b': 2, 'a': 3, 'c': 1}
>>> for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
...     print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
...     
a: 3
b: 2
c: 1
>>> for key, value in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
...     print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
...     
c: 1
b: 2
a: 3
```

Using an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is not an option here, because you don't want to maintain order, but want to sort with different criteria.

Comment: That's strange. I copied the code and the result from my Python console.